# Failed to execute 'toDataURL' on 'HTMLCanvasElement': Tainted canvases may not be exported

Tags: amazon-s3, html5-canvas, cors

I have a canvas that was created by a user (me) dragging an image onto a dropzone. As part of saving the image, I call toDataURL.

var theCanvas = document.getElementById ("idCardCanvas");

var urlImage = theCanvas.toDataURL ();

This code has worked for months when it was running from one domain, littlecardeditor.com.

I am now in the process of adding this functionality to Radio3, at http://radio3.io/.

Both domains are Amazon S3 buckets, both have the same CORS configuration (clutching at straws here, I don't see why CORS enters into it, since the images come off my hard disk, not from any domain).

I dragged the images from the Desktop, based on advice from another thread here.

None of it makes a difference. It works when I use it on littlecardeditor.com and fails with the "tainted canvas" error when called on radio3.io.

Not sure what else to look at. Any clues would be much appreciated! :-)

Comment: browser == chrome? any relevant security settings? If this were IE, I'd ask if the two sites were in different zones, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: Hey Dave, have you saw this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image